# Django manytomany relation save

Tags: django, many-to-many, m2m

i have two models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Auth_User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and my view

```
form = publicationform(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit=False)
    f.user = request.user
    f.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('/')
```

and my form:

```
class publicationform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Publication
    exclude = ['user']
```

but when i save show me this messagge:

needs to have a values for field "publication" beforre this many-to-many relationship can be used
please what´s the problem?

Comment: What line of the code is the error coming from? Try inserting import pdb; pdb.set_trace() into the code so that you can see what the object that you are trying to save looks like.

Comment: the line is f.usuario = request.user

Answer (score 0):

In publication, set model = Publication:

```
form = PublicationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit=False)
    f.user = request.user
    f.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('/')


class PublicationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title']
```

Comment: sorry, i already update the question, this is not the error but thanks

Comment: Your indentation was off and it's a bad practice to use `exclude`... use `fields` instead. Also, is `usuario` correct, or do you mean `user`?

Comment: i wrote the code from my mind, not copy paste, sorry but the correct line is f.user = request.user, thanks